# Getting "unable to switch the encoding" warning when trying to call stored procedure in SQL Server for inserting XML data into a Delta table

Tags: sql-server, xml, casting, encode

I am in the process of inserting data from an XML file into SQL server using Biztalk. For this I have created a stored procedure that inserts new records into the table based on the data in the XML file.

I am encountering a problem with the encoding when dropping the file in the receive location.

In the message log it throws this warning:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

And the data is not being inserted in my table.

The XML file is encoded in UTF-8-BOM.

I've tried converting it to UTF-16, UTF-8 but it gives the same warning.

In my SQL stored procedure, I am declaring the 'iXml' variable and casting it to NVARCHAR(MAX):

```
    @iXml XML
AS
BEGIN

 SET @iXml = CAST(CAST (@iXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML)
```

What can I do to correctly encode my XML file? What encoding does SQL expect from  the XML?

Edit: XML snippet

```
<ns0:Vejstykke xmlns:ns0="http://Company.Vejregister.Schemas.Vejstykke_XML">
    <Data>
        <sekvensnummer>483523</sekvensnummer>
        <tidspunkt>2018-01-14T02:08:38.432Z</tidspunkt>
        <operation>insert</operation>
        <id/>
        <kommunekode>0326</kommunekode>
        <vejkode>2901</vejkode>
        <oprettet/>
        <ændret/>
        <navn>Hedvigsvej</navn>
        <vejnavn>Hedvigsvej</vejnavn>
        <navngivenvej_id/>
    </Data>
```

Comment: Can you attach the failing XML? You should be able to reopen/resave the file *without* BOM (notepad++ can do this, as can SublimeText I know for sure). Once the BOM is removed, you should be able to parse it fine

Comment: Hello Xedni. I tried removing the BOM and sending the file with encoding UTF-8, but it gives the same error.

Comment: Then can you include the xml (or a representative snippet) which cases the failure?

Comment: `select cast(cast(@iXML as nvarchar(max)) as xml)` on the xml you provided seems to run just fine for me.

Comment: That's strange. Do you need any more information? The Xml file does not have an encoding declaration. My table uses the NVARCHAR data type for storing the xml data.

Comment: I managed to fix the error. The problem was located in my custom send pipeline that added an XML declaration to the file with a default encoding type.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the error. The problem was located in my custom send pipeline that added an XML declaration to the file with a default encoding type.

Comment: Please consider posting a more complete "before" and "after" so future readers can learn from the issue.  Like some before xml and after xml.  Its important to "give" to the community, even with a self answer.